# Problems with import "C"

Tags: go, gcc, windows-10, environment-variables, goland

I'm trying to get GO to compile a simple test script on Windows 10 using GoLand but am running into problems. Here is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

import "C"

import (
    "math"
)

func main() {
fmt.Println("working")
}
//export add
 func add( a , b int) int {
    return a + b
}
//export Cosine
func Cosine(x float64) float64 {
    return math.Cos(x)
}
```

When I comment out the `import "C"` line the code compiles fine but when its there I get

```
exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

So I installed [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW) and added its `bin` to the PATH variable so that in a cmd prompt I can run

```
C:\GolandProjects\LearnGoProject>gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

However I'm still getting the error. Could anybody suggest how to fix the issue?

Comment: Are you building to get a shared dll? you need gcc for x64, feel free to use msys2. Follow this guide: https://www.scivision.dev/install-msys2-windows/

Comment: Did you restart GoLand after updating your `PATH`? If not, it won't have the updated value.

Comment: @Adrian I restarted GoLand but it still did not work.

Comment: @Santiago I'm not able to download it. That link is dead.